# Virtual wrapper of std::queue<T> does not compile when T has no copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, queue, copy-constructor, move-semantics

I'm using C++11. I encountered a compilation error when writing a simple wrapper for `std::queue<T>`, and using it with a class that does not have a copy constructor.

Following is a snippet to illustrate the problem.

Basically, I have a wrapper for `std::queue<T>`, which has two **virtual** overloads for `push`.

```
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <future>

template <typename T>
class myqueue {
public:
    myqueue() : q() {}
    virtual ~myqueue() {}

    // pushes a copy
    virtual void push(const T& item) {
        q.push(item);
    }
    // pushes the object itself (move)
    virtual void push(T&& item) {
        q.push(std::move(item));
    }
private:
    std::queue<T> q;
};

int main() {
    // Thanks to Yakk for pointing out that I can reduce clutter by using one of std's non-copyable classes!
    myqueue<std::packaged_task<int()>> q;
    std::packaged_task<int()> t([]{return 42;});
    q.push(std::move(t));
}
```

When I try to compile this (ICC 13.2, g++ 4.7.3 on my Linux machine here, and also g++ 4.7.2 on Ideone: http://ideone.com/HwBhIX ), the compiler complains that it cannot instantiate myqueue::push(const nocopy&) because nocopy's copy constructor is deleted.

If I remove the `virtual` modifiers from `push`, this compiles fine (both on my machine and on Ideone).

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

---

P.S.: here is the error stack from Ideone:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/i486-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/allocator.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/deque:62,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/queue:61,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(_Up*, _Args&& ...) [with _Up = std::packaged_task<int()>; _Args = {const std::packaged_task<int()>&}; _Tp = std::packaged_task<int()>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_deque.h:1376:6:   required from ‘void std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::packaged_task<int()>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::packaged_task<int()> >; std::deque<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::packaged_task<int()>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_queue.h:212:9:   required from ‘void std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::packaged_task<int()>; _Sequence = std::deque<std::packaged_task<int()>, std::allocator<std::packaged_task<int()> > >; std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type = std::packaged_task<int()>]’
prog.cpp:13:9:   required from ‘void myqueue<T>::push(const T&) [with T = std::packaged_task<int()>]’
prog.cpp:28:1:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:110:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::packaged_task(const std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&) [with _Res = int; _ArgTypes = {}; std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)> = std::packaged_task<int()>]’
In file included from prog.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/future:1337:7: error: declared here
```

Comment: `std::queue::push(T const&)` is probably declared using SFINAE, i.e. with something like `enable_if<is_copyable<T>::value,...>` so that the member function is present only for instantiations that have a copyable T. However, from the standard I'd think that that function would be instantiated only if it is actually *used* and therefore should not lead to an error in your case.

Comment: gcc 4.7.2 compiles this fine: http://ideone.com/NPUkaS

Comment: It looks like it [works on gcc 4.7.2](http://ideone.com/J7Rram).

Comment: g++ 4.8 compiled it all without problem.
clang++ 3.4 too.

Comment: **_of course_**, after I put the missing semicolon in nocopy.h (at the end, after the class definition)

Comment: @Massa - it's a wonder that was the only compilation error you encountered, I had to type all this code by hand :) 
(the computer I encountered this on does not have internet access :( ); 
I'll edit the question to fix this particular problem.

Comment: @ArneMertz - I looked at the g++ header several times myself, because I thought I was missing something like this, but I didn't find any trace of it... both versions of `push` are defined without any modifiers (aside from the C++0X `#ifdef` wrapper around the move version)

Comment: `g++-4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu4) 4.7.3` still compiles it just fine. I just copied the text from here and pasted into the files.

Comment: You **are** using the `-std=c++11` flags to compile, aren't you?

Comment: @Massa - I guess this means that my installation of g++ 4.7.3 is somehow faulty, then? :(

Comment: I used `-std=c++0x`, actually, but I just tried it with `-std=c++11`, and the problem persists

Comment: Please check that your source files are exactly what is in your question (don't forget that pesky semicolon! :D) and edit your post adding the complete text of the error message, and of `g++ --version`...

Comment: @MichaelKuritzky please don't copy-type the code you have, that's obviously too risky to introduce errors (and to erase the reason for your real problem). If you don't have internet access on the computer, copy the code onto an usb pen drive and upload it from there.

Comment: @MichaelKuritzky in addition it would be very constructive if you could prvide the actual error message from the compiler. At least the first and last 3-4 lines - I assume it's a huge template error stack

Comment: @ArneMertz - I wish I could, but alas, the policy here forbids the use of usb flash drives. This also means, unfortunately, that complying with Massa's request will take a while... :)

Comment: Do you have access to the same compiler on another computer that has internet access? So you could do your trial compilations on that one, giving a faster turnaround time while we try to spot the problem :)

Comment: The computer where the compiler is does not have any connectivity? You can put your code on your LAN and compile it from there, no? How do you enter code to be compiled, all by hand?

Comment: No, we don't have any Linux boxes here with internet access. I'm afraid this is not the place to discuss the company's security policies, though.. :)

Comment: I have edited the question, adding the (abbreviated) error stack. I'll update it with `gcc -v`'s result tomorrow. Thanks for all the help so far :)

Comment: @MichaelKuritzky the `main.cpp` you posted has 15 lines, but the compiler complains about something at line 17, column 12. Obviously the code you posted is *not* the exact same as the compiler tries to compile. Please make sure they are the same. Even if it's only a comment - we can't tell what the compiler complains about if we don't see the exact corresponding code. This includes comments, line indentation and everything else.

Comment: So the first thing you NEED to do is to simplify the problem.  Reproduce your problem using less code where the problem actually occurs.  Try `my_queue< std::unique_ptr<int> >`, a standard no-copy class, and see if it still fails to work.  If it still fails, you just reduced the amount of code required to reproduce by 1/3!  Next, put everything in one `.cpp` file, not a file and two headers.  See if you still get the error *without calling `push`*?  How about if you eliminate `push` from your `my_queue` class, does the error still occur?

Comment: Produce the absolute least amount of code that reproduces your problem, in a single file.  Then copy it by hand to a piece of paper, have a colleague double-check each and every character, carry that piece of paper to an internet connection, and post the result along with a complete command-line of how you invoked it and the resulting error message.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestions when I come back to work tomorrow. :)

Comment: The error message tells us that the `nocopy` copy constructor is being used from `myqueue::push(const nocopy&)`. The problem is clearly that the real `main.cpp` is trying to push an lvalue, which the example code does not - otherwise the compiler would not instantiate `myqueue::push(const nocopy&)`.

Comment: Hi,
I'm very sorry, it seems that I did, indeed, have a little typing error in my code yesterday.
I have, however, now isolated the true problem I was facing, and in a way reproducible in Ideone (gcc 4.7.2). I will now edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Finished editing. Please take another look at the original post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because the c++11 implementation provided by gcc 4.7 is incomplete. When using c++11 you must always use the most up-to-date compiler versions. clang is usually most complete, followed by gcc and, some distance behind, icpc.

---

Following your edit, the code is not compiling any more (clang 3.2 or gcc 4.8), because it's simply wrong. When the template class `myqueue<std::packaged_task<int()>>` is instantiated, the non-template member `virtual void push(const T&)` is instantiated too. However this member calls the deleted copy constructor of `T`, so is illegal, **error**.
(That it compiles for non-virtual `push(const T&)` is dangerous, as you will get an error as soon as you try to use that function.)

To make you code work, you must avoid that. A `virtual` member cannot be a template (which would have allowed you to avoid the problem via SFINAE). But you can specialise `class myqueue<T>` depending on whether `T` is copyable or not. The following code compiles with gcc 4.8 (but not with icpc 13 or clang 3.2, which has a faulty implementation of `std::is_copy_constructible`).

```
#include <queue>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <future>

template <typename T, typename E=void> class myqueue;

template <typename T>
class myqueue<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value>::type>
{
  std::queue<T> q;
public:
  virtual ~myqueue() {}
  // pushes a copy
  virtual void push(const T& item) { q.push(item); }
  // pushes the object itself (move)
  virtual void push(T&& item) { q.push(std::move(item)); }
};

template <typename T>
class myqueue<T,typename std::enable_if<!std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value>::type>
{
  std::queue<T> q;
public:
  virtual ~myqueue() {}
  // pushes the object itself (move)
  virtual void push(T&& item) { q.push(std::move(item)); }
};

int main() {
  std::packaged_task<int()> t([]{return 42;});
  myqueue<std::packaged_task<int()>> q;
  q.push(std::move(t));
}
```

Of course, this is not quite the same as your original code, as there will be no `virtual void push(const&T)` for non-copyable `T`, but I think this is exactly what you want. Alternatively, you could make the offending method pure virtual in the specialisation for non-copyable `T`.

Sorry, that I cannot fix icpc for you, but at least this code seems to be legal C++11.

Comment: The problem with this is that I have to use icpc, and g++ 4.7 is (from what I gather) the latest version (of the headers) they currently support. :(
We'll switch to g++ 4.8's headers as soon as icpc adds support for them...

Comment: @MichaelKuritzky icpc is not ready for C++11 (yet). Using icpc with C++11 was a bad decision. Best is to use clang. (I don't know why Intel is so bad at implementing C++11, they must prioritise other things.)

Comment: the reason we chose icpc is its performance, not its C++11 support. Anyway, the C++11 support there is quite good so far (albeit still not full :( ), and improving with each update.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to be the problem indeed. By the way, shouldn't it be possible to hide the methods (using SFINAE) without specializing the class, but rather on a per-method basis? (once icpc updates their erroneous implementation of `std::is_copy_constructible`, of course)

Comment: @MichaelKuritzky No, you **cannot use SFINAE** (as I explained), because a `virtual` member cannot be a `template`. If speed is important, then consider clang: I found this to be quite fast, competetive with icpc (though this always depends on the code).

Answer (score 2):

`myqueue`'s standard copy constructor calls the copy constructor of `nocopy`. Simply overwrite or `=delete` the copy-constructor and the `operator=` of `myqueue` and you should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work :(
I tried `delete`ing the copy c'tor and operator=, but the problem persists. (in fact, they were `delete`d in the original classes from which I derived this snippet)

Comment: Did you try the 'old' way of preventing unwanted copies by declaring the copy and assignment operator private?

Comment: Just gave it a shot. Now it complains that the copy c'tor is private... :(

Comment: @MichaelKuritzky then the code you posted is not the code you actually have (or the compiler actually tries to compile, to be precise), because there you don't copy any `myqueue` (it compiles fine with delete copy ctor, see here: http://ideone.com/hLV2kl). Please provide your actual `main.cpp`

Comment: @ArneMertz - I did provide the original. As I said, `delete`ing the copy c'tor of `myqueue` didn't help. I guess my gcc/icpc installation is somehow faulty :(

Comment: @MichaelKuritzky when it cries about the private copy ctor it tries to copy the `myqueue`, obviously. But there is no copying in your code. Try a sole `int main() { myqueue<nocopy> q3; }` - and be sure to save the sources so the compiler actually sees what your editor shows you.

Comment: It complains about an attempt to use `nocopy`'s copy c'tor, not `myqueue`'s one. I'll try your suggestion tomorrow, thanks. :)